# How to build carousel slider

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Hello everyone first of all I wasn't able to find this kind of carousel anywhere for free, so I need advice about how to build it what it needs to be built.

[Here is the image of the carousel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZHMo.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Flicity](https://flickity.metafizzy.co/)

they also have [react-flicity-component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-flickity-component) package for reactjs and it is easy to use

Comment: Thanks I ll take a look at it